# Understanding fonts for vector maps

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl, tile-server

I am serving a custom vector map using Tileserver GL. Everything works as expected, but I just don't want to die dump. So... there is directory called (in my case) `glyphs` with subdirectories like e.g. `Open Sans Bold`. And in there are files `0-255.pbf`, `256-511.pbf`, ...

Can anybody tell me what those files are? So what e.g. does the 0-255 mean?

In my simple working brain, I'd say the map-renderer would need to have the font-files for that font, but why is it split into so many sub-files? I just don't really understand it :)

Would be great if somebody could shed light into this for me.

The background why I am asking. I have my custom offline-implementation, and it seems that my renderer (Mapbox-iOS) won't render certain areas, if it can't get those files. So I need to understand how to also make those offline-available :)

Comment: Are you sure it is `.pbf` and not `.pfb`?

Comment: Yes... https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format